# Firebase Admin Node.js: error "IAM Service Account Credentials API has not been used in project before or it is disabled"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to create a custom token for Firebase authentication in Node.js, but I am getting the following error.

The code I am using is:

```
    admin.auth()
        .createCustomToken(uid)
            .then((customToken) =>
            {
              })
            .catch((error) =>
             {
             });
```

Error message:

> IAM Service Account Credentials API has not been used in project before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iamcredentials.googleapis.com/overview? then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.; Please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens for more details on how to use and troubleshoot this feature.

I enabled the IAM Service Account Credentials API from the [Google Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) console, but hours later I am still getting the error. How can I fix it?